# What is the "off-side engine generator" on an A320?

Tags: airbus-a320, electrical-system

For the A320 family, is the "off-side engine generator" the same as the "emergency generator driven by the RAT"? I can't find the location of the "off-side engine generator" on the A320.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Offside simply means *opposite,* and it's to do with the AC bus supply priority.

For the A320 the priority is:

1. Onside, e.g., left engine IDG for AC BUS 1
2. External power
3. APU
4. Offside, e.g., right engine IDG for AC BUS 1, meaning the left engine's IDG has failed or taken offline.

Answer (score 2):

Neither the off-side and on-side engine generators are RAT generators. They are both just the [generators attached to each engine](https://www.slideshare.net/alkhaldy70/airbus-a320-aircraft-operation-manual). As far as I can tell, if there is a failure of one of the parallel electrical buses the off side is the failed side and the on side is the operating side.